# Could anyone tell me the effective way to migrate from osCommerce to Magento?

Tags: migration

I opened e-commerce store that used osCommerce and now I want to migrate it to Magento with 30000 entities.

Comment: Did you manage to get your question answered?

Comment: Yes, I used a migration tool named LitExtension and were satisfied with their service!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your shop and needs. Both solutions below only offer migration of catalog (and sales) data. Any other data like CMS pages etc you will have to write a script for yourself. I've used both options below with success several times. From the number of entities you've stated I'd go with option 1, the second option has a price based on catalog size which could get quite expensive.

**1. custom**

On highly customized shops (specially on the database) it's best to write your own migrations. You'll need to generate CSV's containing the BigCommerce shops products, categories and customers. For Magento I'd suggest using [AvS FastSimpleImport](http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/) which is a wrapper of Magento's Dataflow import (which is a bit wonky)

**2. paid service**

For simple, default shops I would go with Cart2Cart. I'm not in the habit of promoting paid services but as far as migrations go they provide a very good and reliable platform. You'll have to install a file in either shop which will connect the stores and transfer categories, products, customers and orders